# Need help with Promises in lightning

Tags: javascript, lightning, promises

In my Lightning application I need some helpers to make their calls after others have completed, so I'm trying to implement promises to make that happen in my init function:

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper){
    component.set("v.totalAssignments", 0);
    component.set("v.isAllReassignReferrals",false);
    component.set("v.strSelectedDistance", "Currently Assigned");
    component.set("v.strSubReferralSearch", "All");
    component.set("v.strSalesRepName", "");
    component.set("v.strSelectedUser", "");
    component.set("v.isSalesRep", false);
    component.set("v.selectedUserId", "");
    component.set("v.homeFacilityfield", "");
    component.set("v.strCustomError", "");
    component.set("v.selectedType", "All");
    component.set("v.sortField", "name");
        //helper.getLoggedInUser(component);
        //helper.getS2Permissions(component);
        //helper.getIsSalesRep(component);
        //helper.getUsersList(component);
        //helper.getAccountList(component);
        //helper.getBusinessList(component);
        //helper.getDistanceList(component);
        //helper.getSourceList(component);
        //helper.getStatusList(component);

        helper.helperFunctionAsPromise(component, helper.getUsersList)
            .then($A.getCallback(function() {
                return helper.helperFunctionAsPromise(component, helper.getLoggedInUser)
            }))
            .then($A.getCallback(function() {
                return helper.helperFunctionAsPromise(component, helper.getS2Permissions)
            }))
            .then($A.getCallback(function() {
                return helper.helperFunctionAsPromise(component, helper.getIsSalesRep)
            }))
            .then($A.getCallback(function() {
                return helper.helperFunctionAsPromise(component, helper.getAccountList)
            }))
            .then($A.getCallback(function() {
                return helper.helperFunctionAsPromise(component, helper.getBusinessList)
            }))
            .then($A.getCallback(function() {
                return helper.helperFunctionAsPromise(component, helper.getDistanceList)
            }))
            .then($A.getCallback(function() {
                return helper.helperFunctionAsPromise(component, helper.getSourceList)
            }))
            .then($A.getCallback(function() {
                return helper.helperFunctionAsPromise(component, helper.getStatusList)
            }));
        },
```

The helper involved in that:

```
helperFunctionAsPromise : function(component, helperFunction){
    return new Promise($A.getCallback(function(resolve, reject) {
        helperFunction(component, resolve, reject);
        }));
    },
```

Oddly enough, the first function, the getUsersList, will execute, or whatever is in the first position, but then none of the others will, and I haven't been able to catch any errors or find what may be wrong in the structure.  It just doesn't move to the next item in the chain.

If it matters, I'd like to set them up to fire in sequence with the way they're commented in the list above the promise structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely forgot to "resolve" your promise. Make sure your helper methods are calling resolve/reject to continue the chain or call your failure handler, as appropriate.

```
helper.helperFunctionAsPromise(component, helper.method1)
  .then(() => helper.helperFunctionAsPromise(component, helper.method2))
  .then(()=> helper.helperFunctionAsPromise(component, helper.method3));
```

Comment: Yes, that was correct.  I was resolving them, but improperly.  Correcting that got them working as intended.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not SUPER familliar with lightning, but it does look like you're calling $A.getCallBack twice per method. You create a function, use $A.getCallBack, wrap it in a promise, return the promise and then immediately call $a.getCallback on the promise. I'm not sure if this is intentional or not.

The only one that doesn't seem to have this called twice is the first one which might explain why it's the only one that works.

**EDIT:**

After a little bit of research, I'm a bit more confident in my answer as the second time you call $A.getCallback is from within the normal lightning stack which is not when you're supposed to use it. Using it in the promise is correct.